# Sum/product of two eigenvalues of different matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda_1$ be an eigenvalue of $C$ and $\lambda_2$ be an eigenvalue of $D$ ($C,D$ both $m \times m$ matrices). Prove or disprove the following statements

1.$λ_1+λ_2$ is an eigenvalue of $C+D$

2.$λ_1λ_2$ is an eigenvalue of $CD$

My attempt at the two problem seems to be on the right path, but I keep getting messed up somewhere. I would greatly appreciate a step by step answer to see where I am messing up. Thank You!
Edit: I got True for both, but I don't believe that is correct.

Comment: Probably the downvotes alerted you already. If they did not: It is usual on this site to show us your work, which makes it easier to help you. Moreover, you saying that 'you are on the right path, but keep getting wrong things' and 'hope for a step by step answer' does not really help in convincing people that you actually tried something. So keep in mind, for your future questions, to show us some of your thoughts on your question. Anyway, I gave an answer, since you appeared to be convinced that both questions were true.

Comment: @Student you are doing the Lord's work.

Comment: @TheCount: the good Lord by pointing out how he could improve his questions or the dark Lord by doing that, but still giving him the answer? :p

Comment: @Student both, if you asked me. i lost my patience for explaining things as thoroughly as you have long ago. though unlike some users, i am not averse to giving an answer even if the question shows little effort. it is as beneficial to the helper and the helpee.

Comment: @TheCount: I do not really mind for effort, but I equally understand why the more experienced users are getting irritated by such questions (even if the OP states that 'they feel that they are on the right path, but still have some troubles and would like a step by step answer... legit, isn't it?) :D

Comment: My bad guys, Just frustrated with the question, didn't want to post my solution cause it was horrible.

Comment: @Student yeah, i see the argument, but there are bigger things to worry about in life, in my mind.

Comment: @Rex it's all good. no worries.

Comment: @Rex: it are just hints for your questions in the future... It will make people more willing to answer your questions, nothing more nothing less :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Not true: Consider the matrices
$$C = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix} \quad D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then clearly $2$ is an eigenvalue of $C$ and also of $D$, but $2 + 2 = 4$ is not an eigenvalue of 
$$C + D = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
2) Not true: Try to use the previous counterexample.